# How to connect to Azure Oracle 12c Database using sqlplus or sql developer cloud connection

Tags: database, azure, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle12c

I have 2 VM in azure one is a DB server and the other is a web server.

I can get remote desktop connection for both these servers and web server can connect to Database wih

```
sqlplus user/password@internal_network_ip:port/sid
```

But however I cannot connect to Cloud DB from my local system.
I tried

```
sqlplus user/password@internal_ip:8552/sid
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
sqlplus user/password@xxxx.something.net:8552/sid  -- oracle port
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
sqlplus user/password@xxxx.something.net:54955/sid -- port for cloud system used when taking remote desktop connection
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
sqlplus user/password@server_hostname:8552/sid
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

However I cannot connect to the Database

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to open an endpoint on the cloud service into which your Oracle DB has been deployed.  I would recommend you make the public port something other than the default Oracle port.

See the [Azure documentation site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/) for instructions on how to create endpoint.