# Connect to an Oracle Database on Azure

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to create and use an Oracle DB instance on Azure. I have selected the Oracle + Microsoft VM image to create the VM. The deployment succeeded.
But I cannot find a way to remotely connect to the VM.

Azure points to a link [Connect to your virtual machine.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=403209)
But I cannot find the relevant info.

Comment: Did you create through ASM or ARM? Did you open the endpoints either on the NSG or the cloud service? Did you open up the internal firewall? Did you place the vm in a vnet?

Comment: If you haven't configured endpoints or inbound traffic rules, please look at [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/737796/99269) I posted which shows how to do this, either with Classic VM's (endpoints) or Resource Manager VM's (network security groups).

Comment: Same question and answer here
[How to connect to Azure Oracle 12c Database using sqlplus or sql developer cloud connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591569/how-to-connect-to-azure-oracle-12c-database-using-sqlplus-or-sql-developer-cloud)